# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Parenting Stack Exchange](http://parenting.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What to do if my new-born child urinated into own ear?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14302/what-to-do-if-my-new-born-child-urinated-into-own-ear)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How can I help my son develop a social life? How can I prevent him becoming socially isolated?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/13965/how-can-i-help-my-son-develop-a-social-life-how-can-i-prevent-him-becoming-soci)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How important is a diverse diet for a pre-schooler?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/13989/how-important-is-a-diverse-diet-for-a-pre-schooler)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What are the merits of TV vs DVD?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14276/what-are-the-merits-of-tv-vs-dvd)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How does Elimination Communication work?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14314/how-does-elimination-communication-work)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is the recommended daily allowance of each food group for 10 months olds](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14203/what-is-the-recommended-daily-allowance-of-each-food-group-for-10-months-olds)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What can I do to prevent two well-behaving siblings from turning into a maelstrom of destruction when combined?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/13992/what-can-i-do-to-prevent-two-well-behaving-siblings-from-turning-into-a-maelstro)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Four year-old likes ripping things](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14101/four-year-old-likes-ripping-things)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How to comfort our infant with fever?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14036/how-to-comfort-our-infant-with-fever)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Understanding the idea of "fears" as a young child](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/13994/understanding-the-idea-of-fears-as-a-young-child)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

Answer (score 1):

My experience with parenting.se is that there are some awesome regulars who ask questions because they care about their children a lot and want to find the best for them... that there are a lot of one-off questions for those who are worried about their child(rens) medical welfare and then look for help online -- which is better suited for a medical professional.

There doesn't appear to be as much in the middle-ground.  Almost as if most parents go about raising their children as best they know how and don't do a lot of searching... until it's medical in nature.

That poses a strong challenge to the forum -- becoming known where questions can be asked instead of an area to "give it a shot" when there's a medical problem.  When I see the non-medical problems (and tbh, the non-I-have-a-kid-that-poops-everywhere problem [since I have no ability to help there]), I'm excited to be able to read and see if there is any help which I can provide.  I can't always, but there are remarkable parents on the forum who provide information which is not in my focus and can help so very many people... if they would only search.

As a semi-aside, thanks to all of you who are so active on the forum in giving it its strength!

Answer (score -2):

Moderation is being used in a heavy handed manner.

See this question for one example: [When do parents in Turkey typically introduce food to their babies, and what kind of foods do they typically start with?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14569/when-do-parents-in-turkey-typically-introduce-food-to-their-babies-and-what-kin)

There is no need to moderate this question.  It's on topic here; it is seeking fact not opinion.  If there is any need for clarity that can be added as comments.

But Beofett then adds a further pointless comment: "why do you want to know this?".

THIS IS POISON.  The OP has asked a specific question and wants the answer to that particular question.  Stop second guessing what people want.  If OP later decides they've asked the wrong question they can come back and try again.

The question might be a better fit on a "culture of Turkey" SE site, but there isn't one.  Claiming that weaning is the same worldwide is just idiotic - see the differences between baby led weaning and graded steps for examples of different approaches.

Comment: Whether on topic or not, this question IMO is a low quality one. As far as I remember I didn't vote to close it, but my impression was very negative. As of right now it is open and , as far as I can see, it was Beofett who reopened it. Perhaps his comment was uncalled for, but your very strong statement here also seems a bit toxic. In the end, the site is moderated by us, and if most people deem something off-topic, it becomes off topic.

Comment: Why do you want to know this is pretty important to answering a question, because it guides how to answer the question such that it matches the asker's expectations.  In that particular question, whether the asker was asking because she was generically curious, because she was hoping to be 'normal' socially, because she was curious about availability of produce, etc., are all highly relevant to what sort of answer is appropriate to the question.

Comment: And I think the 'weaning is the same worldwide' was meant to suggest that the physical mechanics of weaning aren't location specific, not that there aren't cultural differences.  All of what you quoted - BLW, graded steps - are not geographic in nature, but are commonly practiced worldwide in the same locations.

Comment: To clarify: at no point did I post a comment saying "why do you want to know this?".  My first comment indicated that the OP was asking several seemingly separate questions. I asked the OP to clarify what they were looking for. The OP clarified. I then reopened it, and suggested to the OP that it would **help people answer** if she provided more context.  I'm sorry you feel that that was heavy-handed, but the question was gathering downvotes prior to my intervention. The question was re-opened after receiving edits, yet still has no answers.

Comment: My actual comments:

Comment: "You seem to be combining several questions here, each of which may already have answers in other questions posted here. Baby developmental milestones do not, to my knowledge, change simply due to the nation in which they are born. I'm going to put this on hold; please either clarify what you are looking for (you can use the edit link to modify your post), or search through the site for existing questions on food introduction and self-feeding."

Comment: "@KellieCrosbie I've reopened the question, but it would help people to provide better answers if you could explain why you need to know this. Are you visiting Turkey with your infant? Hosting a Turkish family with an infant? Something else? Please feel free to edit more details into your question to provide some context."

Comment: Remember: if you disagree with an action you can always reflag the post so one of the other moderators can review my actions.  If there are any other posts that you have concerns about please flag them - if you haven't already done so.

Comment: I know I am a bit late, but Beofett's last comment remains true to his every action.  When it is not blatant, he does not cast a final binding vote and when he feels it is, he is always open to the fact that SE works in a way which may reverse his vote.  He has never been capricious in the use of his moderator vote and always conservative in casting it.  Then when cast, as is evident here, follows up when changes are made to ensure that questions are best able to get suitable answers.